# Exposing child's property for binding

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Assume we have a CustomView with Entry (or any other view) inside of it:

```
public class CustomView : ContentView
{
    public CustomView()
    {
        var entry = new Entry();
        Content = entry;
    }
}
```

How to expose entry's Text property to make view's Text property that is bindable? So view's Text property should be two-way bindable and it should be synchronised with entry's Text property.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own BindableProperties. In this case, as it's an entry, make sure the default binding mode is 2-way. Then you can just set the BindingContext of the Entry to the current object, and bind the ContentView.Text to the the Entry.TextProperty.

```cs
public class CustomView : ContentView
{
    public CustomView ()
    {
        var entry = new Entry ();
        entry.SetBinding (Entry.TextProperty, "Text");
        entry.BindingContext = this;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create ("Text", typeof(string), typeof(CustomView), default(string), BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public string Text {
        get { return (string)GetValue (TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue (TextProperty, value); } 
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I tried first. This solution has a problem: each time you type in a text field it unfocuses the field (hides keyboard).